# How many users are working till specify date?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can somebody help me. I have table with about 5000 rows.

My query is:

```
SELECT (LTRIM(RTRIM(p.pers_name)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(p.pers_lastname))) AS Users, 
       staz.staz AS StartDate, dt_atldata AS EndDate, 
       CASE WHEN t.dt_atl = 0 THEN 'Working' 
            WHEN t.dt_atl = 1 THEN 'Retired' END AS [Status]
FROM dba.tarn AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dba.darb AS d 
             ON t.darb_id = d.darb_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dba.pers AS p 
             ON d.pers_id = p.pers_id
OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(staz_datan) AS [stazas]
             FROM dba.staz AS s 
             WHERE p.pers_id = s.pers_id) AS staz
WHERE t.dt_tipas = 1 
      AND t.dt_atl <> 2
```

Here is the data returned from my query:

```
User1   2012-01-16 00:00    2012-07-04 00:00    Retired
User2   2007-11-08 00:00    2013-03-22 00:00    Retired
User3   2012-09-13 00:00    2012-01-05 00:00    Retired
User4   2012-02-07 00:00    2012-04-27 00:00    Retired
User5   2013-08-15 00:00    2013-12-23 00:00    Retired
User6   2011-09-01 00:00    NULL                    Working
User7   NULL                    2012-01-05 00:00    Retired
User8   2012-06-19 00:00    2013-02-28 00:00    Retired
User9   2013-11-04 00:00    NULL                    Working
User10  2013-11-11 00:00    NULL                    Working
User11  2012-01-25 00:00    NULL                    Working
User12  2012-09-04 00:00    NULL                    Working
User13  2008-08-04 00:00    NULL                    Working
User14  2008-03-03 00:00    NULL                    Working
User15  2008-08-05 00:00    2013-02-25 00:00    Retired
User16  2011-08-20 00:00    2012-01-09 00:00    Retired
User17  NULL                    2013-05-14 00:00    Retired
User18  2008-08-05 00:00    NULL                    Working
User19  2013-04-02 00:00    2013-08-30 00:00    Retired
User20  2012-12-05 00:00    2013-02-04 00:00    Retired
and etc
```

I would like to get the following result:

**How many users have worked overall(included minus retired users) until specified date.**

Example 2011-08 etc.

Of course the result key will be by years and months.

Which query should I use to get this result?

I need history about past by years and months, how many users have worked...

Comment: Could you add an example of the output you would expect using the data example in the question?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH YourQuery AS (SELECT (LTRIM(RTRIM(p.pers_name)) + ' ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(p.pers_lastname))) AS Users,
                          staz.staz AS StartDate, dt_atldata AS EndDate, 
                          CASE WHEN t.dt_atl = 0 THEN 'Working' 
                               WHEN t.dt_atl = 1 THEN 'Retired' END AS [Status]
                   FROM dba.tarn AS t 
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN dba.darb AS d 
                                ON t.darb_id = d.darb_id 
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN dba.pers AS p 
                                ON d.pers_id = p.pers_id
                   OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(staz_datan) AS [stazas]
                                FROM dba.staz AS s 
                                WHERE p.pers_id = s.pers_id) AS staz
                   WHERE t.dt_tipas = 1 
                         AND t.dt_atl <> 2) 

SELECT 'Working', ISNULL(DATEPART(year, EndDate), DATEPART(year, GETDATE())) AS year,
       ISNULL(DATEPART(month, EndDate), DATEPART(month, GETDATE())) AS month,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM YourQuery r1 
        WHERE DATEPART(year, ISNULL(r1.EndDate, GETDATE())) * 100 + DATEPART(month, ISNULL(r1.EndDate, GETDATE())) 
                                               >= DATEPART(year, ISNULL(r.EndDate, GETDATE())) * 100 + DATEPART(month, ISNULL(r.EndDate, GETDATE()))
              AND DATEPART(year, ISNULL(r1.StartDate, 1900)) * 100 + DATEPART(month, ISNULL(r1.StartDate, 1)) 
                                               <= DATEPART(year, ISNULL(r.EndDate, GETDATE())) * 100 + DATEPART(month, ISNULL(r.EndDate, GETDATE()))
          )  AS counter
FROM YourQuery r 
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE())),
         DATEPART(month, ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE()))

UNION

SELECT 'Retired', ISNULL(DATEPART(year, EndDate), DATEPART(year, GETDATE())) AS year,
       ISNULL(DATEPART(month, EndDate), DATEPART(month, GETDATE())) AS month,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM YourQuery r1 
        WHERE DATEPART(year, ISNULL(r1.EndDate, GETDATE())) * 100 + DATEPART(month, ISNULL(r1.EndDate, GETDATE())) 
                                               <= DATEPART(year, ISNULL(r.EndDate, GETDATE())) * 100 + DATEPART(month, ISNULL(r.EndDate, GETDATE()))
          ) * -1 AS counter
FROM YourQuery r
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE())),
         DATEPART(month, ISNULL(EndDate, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY year, month
```